# Geometric Description Of a Set In The Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

$$S_1=\left\{z:Im\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0, z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C\right\}$$

$$S_2=\left\{z:Re\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0, z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C\right\}$$

Can someone help me with the geometric description of the above two sets. I have no clue as to where I should start. Thank You!

Comment: The first part is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201796/describe-the-locus-of-points-of-this-fraction

Comment: Start from realizing $z-z_1$ is a vector from point $z_1$ to point $z$. The imaginary part equal zero means the number is real. The ratio of two numbers is real, if the two respecive vectors are...?

Comment: @CiaPan Parallel?

Comment: Right. And two vectors meeting at common point $z$ are paralel iff that common point and their other ends....?

Comment: @CiaPan Basically all three points must be collinear. So S_1 describes a line.

Comment: Correct. How about the second part now? :)

Comment: @CiaPan If the ratios are purely imaginary then the vectors must be perpendicular. So S_2 contains all points 'z' for which the vectors (z-z_1) and (z-z_2) are perpendicular. But how does this help me in finding those poins 'z'?

Comment: Do you know the [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem)...?

Comment: @CiaPan Had done it in school long back! Thanks a ton for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I thought it would be more interesting (and possibly more useful) for you to follow my hints to find the final answer instead of getting it ready to use. Once we got there, however, I added a complete answer to fulfill this site's question-and-answer principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The condition $$\Im\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0$$ means the ratio is a real number. It follows that, geometrically, vectors $z_1z$ and $z_2z$ in the complex plane are parallel. This implies points $z, z_1, z_2$ are collinear, hence the answer:

   - $S_1$ is a line through $z_1$ and $z_2$ (except $z_2$ itself, due to a zero in denominator) if $z_1\ne z_2$,
   - or $S_1$ is the whole complex plane (except $z_2$) otherwise (if $z_1=z_2$ then each point of the plane is collinear with them both, the fraction is $1$ everywhere except $z_2$, where it's $0/0$).
2. The condition $$\Re\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0$$ means the ratio is an imaginary number. It follows that vectors $z_1z$ and $z_2z$ in the complex plane are orthogonal. This implies points $z_1, z, z_2$ form a right angle. By the converse of the Thales' theorem, $z$ lies on a circle whose diameter is the $z_1z_2$ segment. Hence the answer:

   - $S_2$ is a circle, whose diameter is a line segment $z_1z_2$ (except $z_2$), if $z_1\ne z_2$
   - or $S_2$ is empty if $z_1=z_2$ (the fraction is $1$ or undefined in this case).